# A-frame position object according to width

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, aframe

How would I go about converting an object’s length to X coords? I have a box that grows dynamically with a number of spheres inside it laid out from left to right. I want to position the box in the middle of the screen, so it’s center is in the center of the screen. When I create the box element on the page it’s pivot is at the left corner but I can’t work out how to say “put it at the center minus half the width of the box".

Here's the code to create the box:

```
for (var i=1; i<=hudItems.length; i++) {
            var newSphere = document.createElement('a-sphere');
            newSphere.setAttribute('radius', .3);
            newSphere.setAttribute('color', '#ECECEC');
            newSphere.setAttribute('position', hudEl.object3D.position.x+offSet*i + ' 0 0');
            newSphere.setAttribute('src', hudItems[i-1].thumb);
            newSphere.setAttribute('translate', "0 0.6 0");

            var sphereShadow = document.createElement('a-image');
            sphereShadow.setAttribute('src', 'radial-shadow-3.png');
            sphereShadow.setAttribute('rotation', '-90 0 0');
            sphereShadow.setAttribute('scale', '1 1 1');
            newSphere.appendChild(sphereShadow);
            hudEl.appendChild(newSphere);
        }
        sceneEl.appendChild(hudEl);
```

Would appreciate any pointers - there's probably a simple commonly known way to do this that I'm just not aware of yet.

** Update:

Tried using BoundingBoxHelper - I was previously just creating the hud like this:

```
<a-entity id="hud" position="-1.2 -2.39 -7" pivot="0 0 0" ></a-entity>
```

And I even tried this so I could see it:

```
<a-entity id="hud" geometry="primitive: box; width:2; height:2;     depth:2" position="0 0 -7" pivot="0 0 0" ></a-entity>
```

I added this code:

```
var hud = document.querySelector('#hud').object3D;
var helper = new THREE.BoundingBoxHelper(hud, 0xff0000);
helper.update();
    var min = helper.box.min;
    var max = helper.box.max;
    var newX = -1 * (max.x - min.x) / 2;
    hudEl.setAttribute('position', newX + ' 0 0')
```

But I get this error: 
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateMatrixWorld' of undefined
    at $.setFromObject (three.js:7891)
    at $n.update (three.js:41123)
    at c. (tvr2.html:103)
    at TWEEN.Tween.update (tween.js:399)

I should point out that if I log that helper after creating / updating it, it has no "box" property, or geometry.

Comment: Wait for the entity to load first before calculating the bounding box? `addEventListener('object3dset', function (evt) { if (evt.detail.name === 'mesh') { ... })`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to start by getting at the bounding box of the object, including any of its children. [THREE.BoxHelper](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/helpers/BoxHelper) can do this:

```
var object = el.object3D;
var helper = new THREE.BoundingBoxHelper(object);
helper.update();
```

Then, to center the object on the `X` axis:

```
var min = helper.box.min;
var max = helper.box.bax;
el.setAttribute('position', {
  x: -1 * (max.x - min.x) / 2,
  y: 0,
  z: 0
});
```

The math gets more complicated as you add rotation, but that's the general approach.

Comment: Tried a few variations with this but it seems my entity doesn't have a bounding box, updated my question above

Answer (score 0):

These answers are all outdated now.

```
 this._sidePane.addEventListener('object3dset', e => {
      if(e.detail.type === 'mesh'){
        var size = new window.THREE.Box3().setFromObject(object).getSize()
})
```

is working for me